# wget Not Returning Information - Sometimes

Tags: bash, shell, grep, wget

So I've been working on a small bash script this morning, as a way of tracking the sale prices of a specific item online. I provide it with multiple links to various sites, it accesses them with wget, and greps out the prices.

I provide it with a few different URLs which all work, except for the Amazon ones. (grep doesn't return anything, because it either has nothing or a half-loaded page to search through)
[https://www.amazon.com/DEEPCOOL-GENOME-worldwide-integrated-cooling/dp/B01AA1LA4S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AA1LA4S)

and

[https://www.amazon.com/DeepCool-Computer-Case-GENOME-WH-BL/dp/B01AA1LA4S/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&qid=1469589919&sr=8-2&keywords=genome%2Bdeepcool&linkCode=sl1&tag=sciestud09-20&linkId=f70ad0bfcd9ffd746223bd47207a5459](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AA1LA4S)

These two are extremely finicky and return results, but only sometimes. For example, when I run the script the first time, link 1 returns it's results but link 2 doesn't. The seond time around, link 2 might return something but not link 1. I suspect that it has something to do with the load times of these pages, as these two take longer to load than any other of my URLs.

Does wget not halt progress if it doesn't download anything? This is the piece of code that retrieves the prices:

```
PRCs=($(wget -qO- "$LNK" | 
grep -Eo ''"$FNDSTR"'[^\"]+'))
```

Comment: Accessing the first link with `curl` (or just `wget` without the `-q` option) shows that Amazon is returning "503 Service Unavailable", so it's a problem on Amazon's end.  `wget` handles this by outputting nothing and exiting with an error, which is ignored because it's on the left side of a pipe.

Comment: That makes sense as to why I didn't get any results from wget whatsoever...Still though, it returns proper results occasionally.

Comment: "503 Service Unavailable" means something like "We are closed right now, come back later." That status code is usually returned, when they want to limit requests per user or per time. So it is perfectly OK, if sometime you get 503, and sometime 200 and content.